# How to add colours to my python code

Tags: python, tkinter

Just wanting to know how I can add colours to my outputs. Code below:
Using python tkinter gui.

```
    if bmi < 18.5:
        self.answer_label['text'] = "A person with a BMI of " + str(bmi) + " is underweight " 
    elif 18.5 <= bmi < 25:
        self.answer_label['text'] = "A person with a BMI of " + str(bmi) + " has a healthy weight"
    elif 25 <= bmi < 30:
        self.answer_label['text'] = "A person with a BMI of " + str(bmi) + " is overweight"
    elif bmi >= 30:
        self.answer_label['text'] = "A person with a BMI of " + str(bmi) + " is obese"
```

Comment: That will be a bit harder than it seems -- while there is not a full answer, I suggest you to learn to use the str.format method  - https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html  - and also edit your question with an example of the colors you'd like to get.

Answer (score 1):

So, the main problem is that in tkinter, the Label widget accepts a single color.

You might compose your text of various labels, side by side, if you pack each with `.pack(side="left")` - and assign a color to each widget.

That is not too practical.

The other ay of coloring text is using a `tkinter.Text` widget instead.  The problem is that on the opposite side of `Label`, the `Text` widget is too broad and allows a lot of options to format text inside it.  With a couple hundred lines, a program using a "Text" widget as its main component could become a Text Editor for rich text, in the way of Microsoft Word.

The downside is that documentation is hard to find, with few examples, and incomplete. (That is my main  motivation in getting you this answer - one more "real World" example won't be bad).

The most complete (but still lacking) documentation for the Text widget is here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm

By reading it, you find out that to be able to enter colored text in a Text widget you have to pre-configure  "tags" with the text attribute, and then use its `insert` your text using an index as position, and marking up which tags you are using.

I made a subclass of the `Text` widget which hardcodes some style elements (and the "state" configuration), so that it behaves more like a Label - and added two new methods: `append` which allows you to add text to the end of the element, specifying a color and a background color, and `clear`, to clear all its contents and start over.

The idea is that you use the "ColoredLabel" class I list bellow in place of your "Label" widgets. As it inherits from a tkinter Widget, methods such as "configure", "pack", "grid", will work normally  - and then use its "append" method to create its contents:

```
# boilerplate to assert working under Python 2.7 as well as Python 3:
try:
    import tkinter
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tkinter

class ColoredLabel(tkinter.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent, text="", **kw):
        params = {"relief": "flat", "border": 0, "height": 1, "highlightthickness": 0}
        kw.update(params)
        super(ColoredLabel, self).__init__(parent, **kw)
        self.tags = set()
        self.length = 0
        self.append(text)

    def clear(self):
        self["state"] = "normal"
        self.length = 0
        self.delete("1.0", tkinter.END)
        self["state"] = "disabled"

    def append(self, text, color=None, background=None):
        """Inserts text at the end of the existing text.
        Colors passed in the parameter are used for inserted text
        """
        self.length += len(text)
        tagname = "{}_{}".format(color, background)
        if tagname not in self.tags:
            params = {}
            if color: 
                params["foreground"] = color
            if background:
                params["background"] = background
            self.tags.add(tagname)
            self.tag_config(tagname, **params)
        self["state"] = "normal"
        self["width"] = self.length
        self.insert(tkinter.END, text, (tagname,))
        self["state"] = "disabled"
```

And if yours "answer_label" attribute is defined as a "ColoredLabel", you just write your code as:

```
self.answer_label.clear()
self.answer_label.append("A person with a BMI of ")
if bmi < 18.5:
    self.answer_label.append(str(bmi), "yellow")
    self.answer_label.append(" is underweight ")
elif 18.5 <= bmi < 25:
    self.answer_label.append(str(bmi), "green")
    self.answer_label.append(" has a healthy weight")
elif bmi >= 30:
   self.answer_label.append(str(bmi), "red")
   self.answer_label.append(" is obese")
```

(Of course, if you want the whole label to be the same color, `Label` has support to it - just do `self.answer_label['foreground'] = 'red'` on your original text)